# Save Results in a list and give the list out to a csv

Tags: list, csv, apache-tika

I work with Tika File Detector. It checks which file Typ my file is.

At the moment my Code is like this

```
if (Type.endsWith("application/msword")){ //Match if its .doc
    }

    else if (Type.endsWith("application/vnd.ms-powerpoint")){ //Match if its .ppt
    }

    else if (Type.endsWith("application/vnd.ms-excel")){ //Match if its .xls
    }

    else if (Type.endsWith("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")){ //Match if its .docx
```

Now I want to Store the Result in a list, which list has two entries. When I checked all files I want to save the list in a csv file.

I tried this with a hashmap but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use parallel arrays.  I'm guessing one for the file name and one for the file type, but there is no need to store the info in a temporary data structure if you are just writing to .csv.

If you want to write filename, mime string and extension to a csv, do something like this, where you iterate through your files in main()...

```
 static Tika tika = new Tika();
 static MimeTypes mimeTypes = TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig().getMimeRepository();


 static void processFile(Path p, Writer writer) throws IOException, MimeTypeException {
    String mimeString = tika.detect(p);
    MimeType mt = mimeTypes.forName(mimeString);
    writer.write(String.format("%s,%s,%s,%n",
            p.getFileName(),mimeString,mt.getExtension()));
}
```

You'll want to add exception handling, and it is always better to use a genuine CSV writer (see Apache Commons csv) than to "hope" than none of your data has a comma/newline or to roll your own.